# cv::imshow will not recognize an interleaved pointer wrapped in a cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, pointers, mat, imshow

I have two functions that pass images using pointers

funct 1: Read a gray image from file, do image processing. Convert the processed image to color (3-channel). Wrapping it in a pointer.

funct 2:  have an image pointer as input. Wrap it in a cv mat and show it. Do some other things.

```
funct 1:
cv::Mat imIn = cv::Mat(height, width,CV_16UC1);
cv::Mat outImage;

// read image
std::ifstream ifs{ imagesPathVec, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary };
if ( ifs.is_open() )
{
 ifs.read( reinterpret_cast<char *>( imIn.data ), imIn.total() * imIn.elemSize() );
 ifs.close();         
}
imIn.convertTo(outImage, CV_32F);

//... some image processing applied to outImage

outImage.convertTo(outImage, CV_8UC1);

//wrapping the pointer outStreamBuffer in a cv::Mat.
cv::Mat outStream(height, width, CV_8UC3, static_cast<uint8_t*>(*outStreamBuffer));

// Try two methods to convert  to color images. 
//Method 1.
std::vector<cv::Mat> images(3);
images.at(0) = outImage;
images.at(1) = outImage;
images.at(2) = outImage;
cv::merge(images, outStream);

//Method 2.
cv::cvtColor(outImage, outStream, CV_GRAY2RGB);


Function 2
//wrap the incomming pointer inStreamBuffer in a Mat
cv::Mat inImage = cv::Mat(height, width, CV_8UC3, static_cast<uint8_t*>(*inStreamBuffer), width*3);

cv::imshow("m_inImage ", inImage);
cv::waitKey(10);
```

Since it is a gray image with 3 channels. I try to convert it to color by calling `cvtColor()` before the call to `cv::imshow()`

```
 cv::cvtColor(inImage, inImage,CV_RGB2BGR);
```

but the results were the same.

The displayed image is
[image]

I would appreciate if you can help me to show the image correctly. Also help me to underestand what it is going on. Why opencv is not recognizing its own interleaved image?

Comment: "Since it is a gray image with 3 channels"?

Comment: How does the `outImage` looks like before doing the merge/cvtColor ?

Comment: `CV_RGB2BGR` -- What do you expect that to achieve? All that does is swap red and blue channels...

Comment: @macroland Some color overlay will be added to that gray image with 3 channels. I constructed that way. It is a requirement. there are other functions that expect it that way.

Comment: @ Dan Masek the call to ctColor() was a desperate attempt to see if I find a way to make imshow to see some order in the image

Comment: @api55 What you seing I think is a third of the image repeated 3 times as channel B, then the second third repeated three times in channel G. The last third in channel R. It is like instead of encoding RGBRGBRGBRGB is actually doing RRRRGGGGBBBB ... But thanks, I think I am going to write some code to recover the three bands... However, I am puzzled of why this behaviour.

Comment: @CaribeGirl that is why i asked how the greyscale image before the merge looks like, it could be already wrong from before the function

Comment: Thank you very much to all of you. The problem was the byte size of the inStreamBuffer. the func1 and 2 are communicating through MPI. inStreamBuffer was set for a 16 bit image instead of 8-bit 3 channel one. That's why I see the black rows in the bottom of the image. I realize this error (I was not looking in there) when I try to pass an 8-bit gray image. In this case MPI protested that the size of inStreamBuffer was too small...